# Windows 8.1 File Backup Before Factory Reset

Tags: windows, backup, windows-8.1

It would appear some major changes have occurred in Windows 8.1, specifically how files can be backed up for a factory reset. Normally I would make a backup of all personal files with "Windows Easy Transfer" then format the OS to a base Windows install. At which point I could run "Windows Easy Transfer" and restore all my files to my freshly formatted PC without issue.

Now in Windows 8.1 it would appear you can no longer make a backup of your current PC and Microsoft has stated that they are no longer supporting easy transfer. So what is the best way to make a backup of your personal files before doing a reset in Windows 8.1. The current OS has some nasty viruses and a refresh doesn't seem appropriate do to the current state of the OS. So I would like to perform a reset (factory reset) and restore the files onto my fresh install.

I have been looking at "File History" which appears to be Microsoft's new way of backing up files but I can't find any information about how or if you can recover all your files from "File History" on a new OS. All the information I see points to recovering a file on the current OS if the file is deleted or damaged.

I like many others really liked the safety and catch all of using easy transfer. I have made backups of files only to find I missed a folder here or there and can never get said files back. That issue was eliminated with "Windows Easy Transfer" and now with that being gone my goal is to find the safest/best solutions.

Answer (score -1):

As of Windows 8.1 "Windows Easy Transfer" only transfers one way and can no longer be used to backup your data to move to a new system or restoring your data after a factory reset.

As of Windows 7 and up you can setup "File History" to an external drive or network drive. This can be used to backup your files and restore them to your new system. After making a backup of your files, which could take a while, you can verify the content of your backup folder

```
(Drive Letter):\(User)\(PC Name)\Data\C\Users
```

After you have verified the contents you can safely format your system. After your system is back up simply go to your "File History" settings and select the drive you stored your backup on. The system will see that a previous backup was made and ask you if you want to restore the files before making a backup.